# UIWebview and facebook wall

Tags: objective-c, ios, facebook, facebook-graph-api

I have a small problem with opening the facebook wall in UIWebview. I have access_token and friends id saved in my local database. Now, I would like to open the UiWebview to show the users wall. It seems it is only possible to fetch the feeds from the user profile in the form of json. Is it really possible to display the users wall with the user id and access_token.

I could fetch the users wall feed in the form of json simply as;

```
https://graph.facebook.com/<user_id>/feed?access_token=<access_token>
```

But, this in json format. Is there any way to get the feed in html form or login to facebook such that it stores the cookie in uiwebview with my existing token.

Comment: in objective C it is advisable to use Json for these feeds in ios .. and if you want to use webview only then ... make one webview .. and then open facebook page in there everything will be handled there only .. but if you want to use your access token and user id you have to use graph api in iphone

Answer (score 1, accepted):

To use webview to see the feed without use Json, just make a URL Resquest with the mobile URL from your Facebook Page.

Like this:

```
http://m.facebook.com/<user_id>
```

It's not necessary the Access Token to do this.

Best Regards.